# Customizing a Loadings Plot from a MixOmics Package

Tags: r, figure

I am trying to adjust the order in which the bar plots generated from a loadings graph is shown. Currently, it shows Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, then Petal.Length. I want to see if I can manually adjust the order on the plot by adjusting the plotLoadings() command line (from top to bottom) Petal.Width, Petal.Length, Sepal.Width, and Sepal.Length.

Then, I want to be able to manually change the color of each bar plot, where I can assign blue to Petal.Width and Sepal.Width, and green to Sepal.Length and Petal.Length.

My guesses from searches online would be to use a scale_manual_fill or something for colors, but for adjusting the order for the bars, I am a bit stumped there. Any suggestions would be much appreciated please. Thanks!

```
if(!require(mixOmics)) install.packages("mixOmics", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
suppressWarnings(library (mixOmics, verbose = FALSE))

data(iris)

# Prepare the data
X <- iris[, 1:4]  # Predictor variables
Y <- iris$Species  # Response variable

# Perform PLSDA
plsd <- plsda(X, Y, ncomp = 2)  # Set the number of components as 2

# Plot the loadings
plotLoadings(plsd, comps = 1, main = "PLSDA Loadings")
```